# Moderator Elections ?

Tags: support, moderators

It's been more than a month since we exited beta, and so I'm wondering when we might have our moderator elections.  Anyone have any information ?

Update: crosposted on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74000/moderator-elections-on-sites-that-are-30-days-out-of-beta)

Comment: I figured that if anyone, you would know.

Comment: nope. I'm not plugged into the general moderator zeitgest. But some folks here lurk at meta.SO and I thought they might have heard something

Answer (score 6):

The answer provided [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74000/moderator-elections-on-sites-that-are-30-days-out-of-beta/74004#74004) is, essentially, correct:

> Moderator elections were put on hold due to the Christmas holidays and limited traffic, so I doubt we can hold SO Inc to the 30 day rule. A little birdie mentioned elections will start as early as next week.
>
> <sub>No information has been provided as to which sites, but I would suspect elections over a 1 - 2 months period were required from that time.</sub>